# UIViewController presentVC right after dismissing another one

Tags: ios

I am using the UIImagePickerViewController to allow the user to select images from the library. After that I want to show a custom editing screen. Since UIImagePickerViewController demands on iPhone to be presented modally, I have to dismiss it and right after that show my editing VC.

Unfortunately the background 'flickers' between the views when I set animations to false. Any idea how I could avoid seeing the background between switching from the UIImagePickerViewController to my custom VC?

Thx!

Currently my code looks like this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

}];
[self presentViewController:self.croppingViewController animated:NO completion:^{

}];
```

When enabling animations the flicker is obviously gone, but the time between is very annoying.

Comment: Why not put your presentViewController code inside the completion block of dismiss?

Comment: Try presenting the crop view controller from inside the completion block of dismissViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: the pause inbetween is actually bigger if I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea -- present the imagePicker from inside your crop view controller:

- In the cropper's viewDidLoad, hide self.view
- In viewDidAppear, present a modal imagePicker with the presentation style OverFullScreen
- In your imagePicker delegate methods (didFinish/cancel), unhide self.view
- Dismiss the imagePicker with animation.

The cropper's view will be there when the animation completes.